# python lambda not able to import user defined modules

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.6

I have a python lambda which turns out to be a bit long so we decided to split it into modules. and now when i try to import the module in the `lambda_handler` its seems to be giving following error 
`Unable to import module 'defghi': attempted relative import with no known parent package`
abc.py  which has got `lambda_handler` in it, is trying to import the defghi.py methods as follows

`from defghi import some_method_1, some_method_2`
tried this as well
`from .defghi import some_method_1, some_method_2`

1. both the files are in the same directory
   any sort of help would be appreciated, Thanks in adavance

Comment: `def` is a reserved keyword in python. why use it. also do you have a file named `__init__.py` in all folders of your module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got that working it was the build scripts which where causing the issue in my project.

The build script which created the zip file where expecting only one `.py` file in the directory which was a problem. So the zip created never had other files which then gave error cannot import.

So to answer the question its perfectly fine to split the big lambdas into modules and keep them a bit readable and import into the main `lambda_handler` the required modules.

Comment: I'm running into this problem, how did you fix it?  I don't have a build script, I'm using the sam plugin for Pycharm.  This wasn't a problem at all with the module directory or anything?

Comment: @Books try using lambda layers for shared modules (common code) across lambdas.For me at lest it was nothing to do with module directory or anything.

Comment: Turned out PyCharm was lying to me.  It wouldn't let me simply import a class in the same directory because I had messed with the package names and it no longer recognized the directory as the source directory.  I needed to edit the .iml file in the .idea directory.

Comment: - The `lambda_hanlder` should be at the base of the root of the zip.
 - User `pip install -r requirements.txt -t .` for creating zip